Is it normal that Rider doesn't do anything about paramref XML documentation tags?
Here is a MRE
/// <summary>
/// Adds two numbers together.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">The first number to add.</param>
/// <param name="b">The second number to add.</param>
/// <returns>The sum of <paramref name="a"/> and <paramref name="b"/>.</returns>
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

I was expecting <paramref name="a"/> to "do" something, but it doesn't, am I using it correctly? It feels useless to add this XML documentation tag if it doesn't change the display compared to just using a instead of <paramref name="a"/>.


Not sure if Rider needs to do anything, but the XML which is extracted has the correct semantics where it is indicated what a and b are meant. The XML could be used to create a web documentation of the API, for example. Your use is correct and you should not drop the XML here.

Thanks for reporting, please upvote this issue: RIDER-117275 Paramref tag in XML docs is ignored in the pop-up
